# How to run web.py with gunicorn?

Tags: python, wsgi, web.py, gunicorn

I have developed a web.py API and server.py has following code at the bottom.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()
```

Now if I run this with gunicorn.

```
gunicorn server:app
```

And it gives me following log

```
2013-11-10 17:11:55 [17158] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2013-11-10 17:11:55 [17158] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (17158)
2013-11-10 17:11:55 [17158] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-11-10 17:11:55 [17163] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17163
Failed to find application: 'server'
2013-11-10 17:11:55 [17163] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 17163)
2013-11-10 17:11:55 [17158] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2013-11-10 17:11:55 [17158] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

What can be wrong? I have used gunicorn before with django app and it worked fine but with web.py I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: ah I had to remove "if __name__ == '__main__':"

Answer (score 0):

Do not write in **main** .

Just write at the end of your code

```
app = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()
```

then

```
gunicorn web:app
```